# Adobe Reader Internet Explorer Plugin does not want to be displayed on the back of an HTML element

Tags: html, pdf, explorer

I've got the following problem:

I'm trying to create a web site to display pdfs.
But I want to display an html overlay over those pdfs

I could accomplish it on chrome just setting a z-index of the top image higher than the `<object>` (pdf)

The problem comes with internet explorer.
Internet explorer needs a plugin in order to display a pdf.
I'm trying the adobe reader plugin, but the problem is when I try to put the overlay over the pdf.
The Adobe Reader Plugin always gets painted over everything.

I've tried to put the pdf inside an iframe but it always gets painted on an overlay.

This is a sample code I'm trying to use

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

[image: overlay]

Comment: I think you have found one of the many reasons that Internet Explorer is the most hated browser for web developers.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used an mozilla open source pdf viewer made with javascript and css called

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/